# Arch Linux dual boot stuck (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, boot, arch-linux, dualboot

I'm trying to dual boot windows with Arch Linux on my Thinkpad T450. However when I try to boot into it (from a USB stick) it brings me to a black screen with a blinking cursor. The Arch Linux distro that I have was set up using Zen Installer, the set up was completed, but when I rebooted it I was brought to the black screen. Is there a way to prevent this from happening,and correctly boot into it?

Comment: Do you see anything before it gets to the black screen?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nope, I just boot into my USB, and get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Comment: What procedure did you follow to put Arch on the USB stick?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I flashed it onto the USB stick using Balena Etcher. The USB stick worked fine running Zen Installer, but when I restarted, and tried to boot, that's when it happened.

Comment: The Zen Installer was started (booted?) from the stick and you installed Arch where?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I would assume that Arch was installed onto the USB

Comment: But you said you used Balena to put Arch on the USB?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Sorry, messed up with my wording, I put the Zen Installer ISO file onto the USB.

Comment: Then you'll understand that it's hard to boot Arch since you don't know where it is.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I believe that Zen Installer adds Arch to the USB.

Comment: Balena Etcher has its own forum, perhaps you can have a try there?